# Import big (My)SQL file

Tags: sql, mysql, ajax, import

I got a crappy connection so I can't use apps like BigDump, that would stop if I can't stay in the page.

What can I do? I'm looking for a way to import without the necessity of keep connected all the time...

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access, you could gzip/bzip2 your dump file and then upload it, and then run the import via commandline on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

use rsync to transfer the files then load it from the cli in a screen session.

That way if your connection fails you can resume